# Codeigniter $query->row_array() SQL $query->result_array()

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

So I am trying to get  a **single** item data like itemID, itemSKU etc. from multiple tables. And display in the view.
The example item I provided down below has three images attached.If I use return $query->row_array(); I will get only one row returned. If I use $query->result_array(), I will get three rows returned. For single item page, I don't want to use foreach to display the result.

**My Model**

```
$this->db->join('itemsToCats', 'items.itemID = itemsToCats.itemId','left');
        $this->db->join('categories', 'itemsToCats.catId = categories.ctgID', 'left');
        $this->db->join('itemImg', ' items.itemID = itemImg.itemID', 'left');
        $this->db->select('items.itemID, itemSKU, itemName, itemSDesc, addDate, chgDate, ctgID, ctgName, parentID, itemImg');      
        $query = $this->db->get_where('items', array('items.itemID' => $itemID));
        return $query->row_array();
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [itemID] => 521
    [itemSKU] => image part number
    [itemName] => multiple images
    [itemSDesc] => 
    [addDate] => 2018-07-12 16:17:09
    [chgDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [ctgID] => 67
    [ctgName] => Pipe Bending
    [parentID] => 46
    [itemImg] => 234-gy_hello1.png
)
```

**If I use return $query->result_array()**
I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [itemID] => 521
            [itemSKU] => image part number
            [itemName] => multiple images
            [itemSDesc] => 
            [addDate] => 2018-07-12 16:17:09
            [chgDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [ctgID] => 67
            [ctgName] => Pipe Bending
            [parentID] => 46
            [itemImg] => 234-gy_hello1.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [itemID] => 521
            [itemSKU] => image part number
            [itemName] => multiple images
            [itemSDesc] => 
            [addDate] => 2018-07-12 16:17:09
            [chgDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [ctgID] => 67
            [ctgName] => Pipe Bending
            [parentID] => 46
            [itemImg] => cac1f0ad0720ac05e76fd990de2d309e.png
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [itemID] => 521
            [itemSKU] => image part number
            [itemName] => multiple images
            [itemSDesc] => 
            [addDate] => 2018-07-12 16:17:09
            [chgDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [ctgID] => 67
            [ctgName] => Pipe Bending
            [parentID] => 46
            [itemImg] => eee779a15e340e2a0f4d0b682e900862.png
        )

)
```

**What I want is this:**

```
Array
(
    [itemID] => 521
    [itemSKU] => image part number
    [itemName] => multiple images
    [itemSDesc] => 
    [addDate] => 2018-07-12 16:17:09
    [chgDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [ctgID] => 67
    [ctgName] => Pipe Bending
    [parentID] => 46
    [itemImg] => Array
        (
            [0] => 234-gy_hello1.png
            [1] => cac1f0ad0720ac05e76fd990de2d309e.png
            [2] => eee779a15e340e2a0f4d0b682e900862.png
        )
)
```

Is there some SQL trick I can use to achieve the data structure, or I need to modify the result data in the model?
Thank you!

Comment: If you can find a safe separator character, you could `GROUP BY itemID` and select `GROUP_CONCAT(itemImg SEPARATOR '<somecharacter>')` and then `explode()` the itemImg value in the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*You can modify your result array like this :*

```
$this->db->join('itemsToCats', 'items.itemID = itemsToCats.itemId','left');
$this->db->join('categories', 'itemsToCats.catId = categories.ctgID', 'left');
$this->db->join('itemImg', ' items.itemID = itemImg.itemID', 'left');
$this->db->select('items.itemID, itemSKU, itemName, itemSDesc, addDate, chgDate, ctgID, ctgName, parentID, itemImg');      
$query = $this->db->get_where('items', array('items.itemID' => $itemID));
if ($query->num_rows() > 0 )
{
  foreach ($query->result_array() as $key => $item) 
  {
    $data['itemID'] = $item['itemID'];
    $data['itemSKU'] = $item['itemSKU'];
    $data['itemName'] = $item['itemName'];
    $data['itemSDesc'] = $item['itemSDesc'];
    $data['addDate'] = $item['addDate'];
    $data['chgDate'] = $item['chgDate'];
    $data['ctgID'] = $item['ctgID'];
    $data['ctgName'] = $item['ctgName'];
    $data['parentID'] = $item['parentID'];

    $data['itemImg'][$key] = $item['itemImg'];
  }
}
//print_r($data);die;
return $data;
```